# How to move data across view-controllers? In a simple Swift-iOS8 way

Tags: xcode, model-view-controller, swift, ios8, protocols

I've read plenty about the How-To about moving data across view-controllers in Swift iOS programming but so far I haven't found a big consensus:

- Temporary models (Unnecessary I think for small data)
- Variable/Placeholders
- Protocols
- Others...

The rules about references and pointers in Objective-C may not apply for Swift, so values flying over in memory with protocols may not be the same, or I don't know (that's why I'm asking).

So, in a very simple but well-done manner, if I have a variable say... - result - of String type in a ViewController1 how can I make it available in a ViewController2? I don't need an Strong link to it, just the value.

Which way would you recommend?

Thank you all very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to "jump" from viewController1 to viewController2 is via a storyboard segue. This segue can be performend in several ways: Directly from storyboard (i.e. from a button) or by code, using `performSegueWithIdentifier` method from a `UIViewController`.

No matter which way the segue is performed, the method `prepareForSegue` is called immediately before the segue is performed. In this method you get a reference to the segue's target viewController where you can pass your variable.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let viewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2 {
        // passing variable from vc1 to vc2
        viewController2.result = self.result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So, you recommend creating a variable in the VC2 expecting a value. I'm little confused about how this method allows me access to a variable that may be at that very moment out of scope.

Comment: The 2nd viewController is already instantiated at that moment when `prepareForSegue` is called so you can access it's variables from viewController1.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much. By the way: its variables... no ' ;-) (its) possessive form of the pronoun it. My two cents :-)

Comment: If it isn't you have a wonderful English and communication capabilities. I really mean it.